Record’s field as formal parameter of procedure in Delphi
I want to create a procedure which performs some manipulations on a variable record type. Globally, I have an array of records. I want to sort the array, but by the records’ fields. I want to pass the field as a parameter to a procedure. And the question is:
How to pass the field of a record as a parameter? For example: Function f2 shall return the field’s value and the field’s offset.
type  TCell = record
    a: byte;
    b: byte;
  end;

function f2(cell: Tcell; offset: byte): byte;
begin
   { ** } result:=cell.offset { ** }
end;

begin
    c: TCell;
    c.a:=10; c.b:=20;
    writeln(f2(c, 2))  // 20;
end;

Is it possible in Delphi? It is certainly possible in FreePascal via pointers, but the following doesn’t work in Delphi and the compiler raises the error:

E2015 "Operator not applicable to this operand type"

function f1(a: pointer; offset: integer): byte;
begin
  f1 := PByte(a+offset)^;  // ← error here
end;

begin
    cell.a:=10; cell.b:=20; 
    writeln(f1(@cell,0));          
    writeln(f1(@cell,1));
end.


Keep in mind record alignment. Your fields will likely not be at 1-byte offsets by default. If you need that, you should declare the record as packed, or use {$A1}

Well, let me first answer your "actual" question:

Globally, I have a array of record. I want to sort the array, but by record's field.

In modern versions of Delphi, you use generics for this:
type
  TCell = record
    a, b: Byte
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

  var Arr := TArray<TCell>(nil);

  TArray.Sort<TCell>(
    Arr,
    TComparer<TCell>.Construct(
      function(const Left, Right: TCell): Integer
      begin
        Result := Left.a - Right.a // no overflow risk
      end
    )
  );

end;



I want to pass the field as procedure's parameter.

Create an enumerated type for the various fields and use a case statement.
You can also use RTTI, but that will not be as performant.

it is certainly possible in Pascal via pointers

You can use pointers in Delphi as well, but this is very rarely good practice unless you are a Delphi expert and really need the absolute best performance or most golfed code.
type
  TCell = packed record
    a, b: Byte
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

  var Cell := Default(TCell);

  Cell.a := 100;
  Cell.b := 200;

  var p := PByte(@Cell);

  ShowMessage(p^.ToString);
  ShowMessage((p + 1)^.ToString);

end;

The trick here is that PByte is declared with pointer arithmetic on. Indeed, in System.pas you'll find
  {$POINTERMATH ON}
  PByte         = ^Byte;        {$NODEFINE PByte}       { defined in sysmac.h }
  {$POINTERMATH OFF}

You can always use this trick on your own pointer types.
Your code
  f1 := PByte(a+offset)^;  //<--- error here

doesn't work because a is a Pointer and offset an Integer and you cannot + a Pointer and an Integer.
But
  PByte(PByte(a) + offset)^

would work.

PByte(a) + offset yields a PByte, no need to type cast it to PByte again. PByte(PByte(a) + offset)^ -> `(PByte(a) + offset)^

@RemyLebeau: I know that. Should have mentioned it, perhaps. Of course, the extra cast doesn't hurt either, and it may help explain what the types are at every level.

What is "most golfed code" meant to be?

@PhilipJ.Rayment: To "golf" code means (at least to me) to write the function, program, or algorithm in as few characters (or lines of code) as possible. See the second definition here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/golf#Verb

@AndreasRejbrand Thanks for that.  I checked eight other online dictionaries, and none of them had that definition.  Maybe Wiktionary made it up! (just kidding).
